# CSS Masonry layout - column-count won't change

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm building a site and loading it onto Wordpress. I have some corporate pages which illustrate images using a css masonry effect. At the moment I have the pages all set to a column-count of 5. I'm thinking of enlarging the images and using a column count of either 4 or 3. However, when I try and change the column count nothing happens. I'm using masonry on the home page for 2 separate sections which are both set at `column-count: 4;` plus I have separate rules for media queries.

I thought I'd sorted this by having them all under different wrapper divs but there's some conflict somewhere that I can't find. I've created a codepen with the full code for one of the pages which works fine [here](https://codepen.io/MikeWhitehead/full/bYdBBR/). I've set the pen at a column-count of 3 so I know this works.

From the pen you can see I've got a div with class "wrapper" to hold the masonry. On the home page I have, for example -

```
<div class="staff">
           <div class="masonry">            
                  <!-- code here -->              
                </div>
        </div>
```

And my media queries for the masonry sections (think the problem may lie in here but I can't seem to locate it) -

```
/* RWD for masonry partner templates */

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }

     .staff .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }

}


@media only screen and (min-width: 480px) and (max-width: 750px)  {
     .staff .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }


}



@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 960px) {      

     .staff .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1300px) {



     .staff .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;

    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {

     .staff .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 560px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 900px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }



}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1280px) {
    .wrapper {
        width: 1260px;
    }
}


/* RWD for 'What we do' */

@media only screen and (min-width: 300px) {

     .whatwedo .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 400px) {
    .whatwedo .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 1;
        -webkit-column-count: 1;
        column-count: 1;
    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 560px) and (max-width: 750px) {

       .cols  {
        -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }

}    


@media only screen and (min-width: 750px) and (max-width: 960px) {


     .whatwedo .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 2;
        -webkit-column-count: 2;
        column-count: 2;
    }


}

@media only screen and (min-width: 960px) and (max-width: 1300px) {


     .whatwedo .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 3;
        -webkit-column-count: 3;
        column-count: 3;

    }

}

@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) {

   .whatwedo .masonry {

      -moz-column-count: 4;
        -webkit-column-count: 4;
        column-count: 4;
    }
}

/* --------------------------------------------- */
```

Comment: How can see your problem? I don't understand

Comment: Its working, changing col count as per screen size (I copied media query from here to codepen)

Answer (score 0):

Apologies - this was, probably, a poorly worded question. The issue was here -

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1100px) {
    .masonry {
        -moz-column-count: 5;
        -webkit-column-count: 5;
        column-count: 5;
    }


}
```

So, when I changed the column-count nothing happened. I've adjusted this now and in the main styling rules and it works.